# issue with identifiers using dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting this runtime error when I run my app in the simulator.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier PlayingCard - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'
```

The line it crashes on is

```
UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCard"
                                                                       forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in the method

```
-(UICollectionViewCell*) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
             cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

As I understand it, the error means the indentifier "PlayingCard" doesn' match up with any of the identifiers of CollectionViewCells in in the CollectionView, but I have made sure that the identifier in the storyboard is identical.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Create a sample project without your real code and mail it to me. I've some time tomorrow. I'll take a look at it. Here is my email: adrianp31@me.com I'll do what I can and will forward you back the solution.

Comment: Just sent the fixed project back to you. Take look at the edited answer please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code of how to implement the cell with identifier for uicollectionview. I hope this helps out

```
 - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 UICollectionViewCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"YourIdentifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
return cell; 
}
```

Also there is a great tutorial on uicollectionview view in ray' web site that would help you understand the whole concept a bit more. Here is the link [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12)

Edit:

The issue with your project crashing was indeed in the storyboard part. You did everything correctly but your cell was never connected. It was an easy fix. I sent you back the project and left you a bit comments in there too.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with your code. For some reason it isn't recognizing the indentifier even though the one in that line of code and the one in the storyboard are identical.

Comment: I don't think you should have a space in the identifier string.

Comment: @connor, be sure you are looking at the identifier of the cell. To make sure you're looking at the cell, open up the document outline and click it to see the identifier. I always enter the value there and then copy/paste into my code.

Comment: @VictorEngel, the issue was not the space in the identifier, it was the connection of the cell in the storyboard where the image gets placed on top of it. Although you were right about the space so I corrected it for future users.

Comment: @AdrianP: Can you please explain to me what you mean with the word "connected"? It seems I got a similar issue.

Comment: @Sebastian Krogull, in the case of above question, he created a class for the cell that he was using but the cell was never connected to that class in storyboard. When he sent me the demo project I realized that. All there was, was to connect the cell to its class in storyboard and it worked. I can't comment on what your project look like but if you need any help my email is in the comments and I'll be glad to look at your project too. Cheers

Comment: Found out what my problem was. I copied over a UICollectionView from Storyboard into IB. Interface builder doesn't support Prototype Cells thought. The cells have to be created separately as XIB to work properly which is odd to be honest.

Comment: That is the way to go as far as the above code is concerned. Glad that your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 7):

Your Error tell detail about your problem

```
must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

If you create UICollectionViewCell class only by code, use register class in viewDidLoad for collectionView

```
 [self.collectionView registerClass:[YourCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"PlayingCard"];
```

If you create UICollectionViewCell by Xib, use registerNib

### If you drag UICollectionViewCell into storyboard, specify UICollectionView class and reuse identifier

I think you forgot to specify class name for your Cell in storyboard

Comment: I created my UICollectionViewCell in storyboard. I specified both a custom class and reuse identifier.

Comment: Show your screenshot and don't register again in viewDidload

Comment: You can discuss now in chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26420/ios-tutorials

Comment: Check picture of Mirko answer. Same?

Comment: Yes. The identifier is set as "PlayingCard" in the attributes of the CollectionViewCell

Comment: @connor I sure this way is correct. You miss somewhere. Go to chat room if you need more help

Answer (score 1):

you should place 
     `[self.tableView registerClass:[UITableViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" ];`
in your init or view did load as stated above and be sure that cell in story board has the same name.

your xml generated in your storyboard should look something like this (except collectionViewCell instead of tableViewCell)

```
<tableViewController id="qqN-Qz-7Na" customClass="ColorPickerSavedColorTableViewController" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                <tableView key="view" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" clearsContextBeforeDrawing="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alwaysBounceVertical="YES" dataMode="prototypes" style="plain" separatorStyle="default" rowHeight="44" sectionHeaderHeight="22" sectionFooterHeight="22" id="jm9-vU-9fK" userLabel="TableView">
                    <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="568"/>
                    <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                    <color key="backgroundColor" white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="calibratedWhite"/>
                    <prototypes>
                        <tableViewCell contentMode="scaleToFill" selectionStyle="default" indentationWidth="10" reuseIdentifier="Cell" id="8ty-Ap-v04">
                            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="22" width="320" height="44"/>
                            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
                            <tableViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" tableViewCell="8ty-Ap-v04" id="Omv-J2-1dd">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="320" height="43"/>
                                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                            </tableViewCellContentView>
                        </tableViewCell>
                    </prototypes>
                </tableView>
                <navigationItem key="navigationItem" id="6MG-Do-Mu4"/>
            </tableViewController>
```

look at the tableViewCell section

Comment: If your not using the built in cell and instead you subclassed it, when you go into story board and select the cell you dragged in, go to the properties and specify the custom class as your subclass.